# angular-ui-router state not loaded on page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have created a website which uses angular-ui-router for mapping to multiple views. Everything works fine except for two things:

1. When navigating to a website without an angular route, no view is loaded.
2. No matter to which url the user navigates, the browser resets the url to my `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise()` value. The view is not altered though.

My main module looks like this:

```
angular.module('package.name', [
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'package.nameControllers'
]).
config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.
    state('home', {
        url: 'home',
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
    }).
    state('other', {
        url: 'other',
        template: 'Another page'
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

I have created the same situation on [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/iAO4fCvF0GAqVZq2GIIg?p=preview). The example of the url not changing can be seen [here](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/iAO4fCvF0GAqVZq2GIIg/#/home).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Urls for top level states should begin with a slash. Try adding the slash:

```
state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
    controller: 'homeCtrl'
}).
state('other', {
    url: '/other',
    template: 'Another page'
});
```

See [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/q9tjF3GtmGhn8x4wy0r4?p=preview).